# How can I use the YouTube API to fetch the title, description, and thumbnail of a video?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm working on a project where I need to retrieve specific information from YouTube videos, such as the title, description, and thumbnail. I've been researching the YouTube API, but I'm still unsure how to implement this effectively.

Additionally, I'm curious about how the pricing of requests to the YouTube API works. Is there any cost associated with each request? Are there different levels of access or subscriptions that affect these prices?

Lastly, I'm interested in knowing if there are other legal ways to obtain this information without using the YouTube API. What alternatives exist and how do they compare in terms of effectiveness and costs?

I would like to know how I can use the YouTube API to gather the title, description, and thumbnail of a video given its ID. Is there any specific library I should use or any code examples I can follow?

Comment: Consider [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint.